# Make WKWebView cover the whole screen

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, wkwebview, safearealayoutguide

I have a WKWebView that I want to cover the whole screen. On newer devices that doesn't have a physical home button, iOS adds a white area under the "homebar". I've tried to override the `safeAreaInsets` witch works fine to make the content to go under the "homebar", but id like to keep the top parameter to its default value. This is since I have a navigation bar at the top witch can be hidden or shown. Setting `UIEdgeInsets(top: 0...` makes the WKWebView go behind my navbar (obviously).

Is there anyway to only override `left`, `bottom` and `right`?

```swift
import Foundation
import WebKit

class FullScreenWKWebView: WKWebView {
    override var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

So i figured it out, and boy, I was wrong. Turns out it wasn't an issue with the constraints but how WKWebView render pages in safe areas. I figured out that my WKWebView covered the whole screen but didn't render the background under the home bar/notch. The dark green color is defined in html.

[image: iPad with wkwebview that didn't cover the whole screen]

My solution to the problem was to disable WKWebViews bultin adjustment.

```
webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

I also created two top constraint for my WKWebView with different priorities. One to safeArea and one to superView. Then I change the priorities in code when the navbar is visible so that the page doesn't render under the navbar.

Result:
[image: Result with no bar]
With constraints to superView

[image: Result with bar]
With constraints to safeArea

Answer (score 2):

Can't you solve this using autolayout, by pinning the webview to either the superview or the safe area, depending on what you want?

Anyway, you could probably do something like this:

```
override var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
    let insets = super.safeAreaInsets
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: insets.top, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

Comment: Pinning WKWebView to its superview still restricts me to safearea. Setting `top: insets.top` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend overriding the `safeAreaInsets` of any `UIView` directly as it might lead to unexpected behaviours as the one you mentioned yourself.

> These `safeAreaInsets` are generated on a higher `UIViewController` level, and therefore should be dealt there.

**I would rather advise doing as follows:**

Add this code to the `UIViewController` that will hold your `FullScreenWKWebView`.

```
 override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
     super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

     additionalSafeAreaInsets.bottom -= bottomLayoutGuide.length
 }
```

This way you will preserve the original `UIViewController`'s `safeAreaInsets` and simply add the desired modifier for the original. Allowing for modification at any stage.